Behaviour of graded Betti number of a module
Let $M$ be a graded finitely generated $R=\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$-module and,
the graded Betti number of $M$ is defined by $\beta_{i,p}^{R}(M)=\mathrm{dim}_{k}(\mathrm{Tor}_i^{R}(M,k)_p)$.
Suppose $u$ be $R$-regular and $M$-regular. Is   $\beta_{i,p}^{R}(M)=\beta_{i,p}^{R/u}(M/uM)$?
In case of total Betti number, they are same. But can similar result holds for graded Betti numbers?

You would first of all like that $u$ should be homogenous

Then will it hold?
